# Format date from database?

Tags: php, date, format

When I pull the date out of the db, it comes back like this:

2009-10-14T19:00:00

I want to format it in two different ways...

The first: F d, Y
The second h:m (12 hour format)

Everything I try returns December 1969...  Help?!  I feel so confused...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Normally the code is just:

```
echo date('F d, Y h:mA', strtotime('2009-10-14 19:00:00'));
```

Note that if `strtotime()` can't figure out the date, it returns the time as [1/1/1970 00:00:00 GMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score 8):

**Simple date display function :**

```
 echo date('m-d-Y H:i:s',strtotime($date_variable));
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to format it in the database (assuming MySQL):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.column, '%M %D, %Y'), --October 14, 2009
       DATE_FORMAT(t.column, '%h:%i %p') --hh:mm am/pm
  FROM TABLE t
```

...or if you want to do the conversion in PHP:

```
echo date('F d, Y h:mA', strtotime('2009-10-14 19:00:00'));
```

Reference:

- [MySQL DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
- [PHP strtotime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 2):

Best of all and clear

```
$res_tbl ='select create_date from tbl_comments';
while($table =mysql_fetch_array($res_tbl))
{
  echo date('F d, Y h:mA', strtotime($table['create_date']));
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
January 10, 2009 21:12
March 21, 2001  12:04
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check [strtotime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)