# How to separate date and time using php from date time string?

Tags: php, datetime

How to convert this string

```
$parent = "2011-08-04 15:00:01";
```

to separate it into two strings:

```
$child1= "2011-08-04";
$child2 = "12:00:01";
```

And then convert

```
$child1 to this format 8.4.2011
```

and

```
$child2 to this format 15:00
```

Comment: Please use the search function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535246/php-format-date-from-database

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$time = new DateTime("2011-08-04 15:00:01");
$date = $time->format('n.j.Y');
$time = $time->format('H:i');
```

Comment: How about the scenario when I want to add 6 hours to parent and then convert it to the new format. What should I do with parent first?

Comment: You can find that information in the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Answer (score 8):

```
$parent = '2011-08-04 15:00:01';

$timestamp = strtotime($parent);

$child1 = date('n.j.Y', $timestamp); // d.m.YYYY
$child2 = date('H:i', $timestamp); // HH:ss
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime( '2015-04-16 15:00:01' ) );
```

this will give you correct date format followed by mysql
i.e 2015-04-16 03:54:17