# Formatting a Date String php

Tags: php, string, date, format

I have got a date string which looks like the following:

```
Thu Feb 09 2012 07:25:00 GMT 0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

I need to convert it to

```
d-m-Y H:i
```

format.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: @Gordon: If you were to do any research on me, then this is my last resort and I did search for the function as I couldn't find which function I would have needed that's when I came here as I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: It's not that hard to find the [date and time functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = 'Thu Feb 09 2012 07:25:00 GMT 0000 (GMT Standard Time)';
$date = str_replace(' 0000 (GMT Standard Time)','',$date);
$date = strtotime($date);
echo date('d-m-Y H:i',$date);
```

Comment: Ah your answer worked straight out of the box. Thanks!

Comment: `substr()` might work better, unless the `0000 (GMT Standard Time)` is always there.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming PHP 5.4+, you can use ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BLOB8A))

```
$d = 'Thu Feb 09 2012 07:25:00 GMT 0000 (GMT Standard Time)';
$obj = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s e +', $d);
```

Comment: You want the `*` to be a `+` (as of PHP 5.4).  The `*` does not do what you think it does (it stops at separators and digits).

Comment: That would have been fine except I am not running 5.4+ I am only running 5.3 :/

Comment: @DarkMantis: Actually, I'd said 5.3+. Gordon changed it to 5.4 for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

how about [Format date from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535246/php-format-date-from-database), [Convert to date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671145/php-convert-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy), [`strtotime()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`datetime formats`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) ?

Comment: I saw them but they weren't any help as mine is quite a bit different

Answer (score 1):

Parse string using substring then use mktime to build date and finally format it using date function.